# Is in JobRunr an AfterFinallyFailedHook

Tags: hook, jobrunr

After a job failed finally no matter if it's out of retries or it's a ProblematicExceptionAndMustNotRetry, I want to react on it.
Is there any hook I haven't seen so far?
Currently I'm using a CustomRetryFilter as follows:

```
public class CustomRetryFilter extends RetryFilter {
   @Override
   public void onStateElection(Job job, JobState newState) {
      if (this.isFailed(newState)) {
         if (!this.isProblematicExceptionAndMustNotRetry(newState)
         && !this.maxAmountOfRetriesReached(job)) {
            job.scheduleAt(Instant.now().plusSeconds(this.getSecondsToAdd(job)),
               String.format("Retry %d of %d", this.getFailureCount(job), this.getMaxNumberOfRetries(job)));
         } else {
            // Publish event
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What is best practice for such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is currently the way to do it.

I'll add a feature request for it.